# Nodejs HTTP Retry Pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, https, azure-functions

JS newbie here!
I am trying to implement a retry logic using the built in https lib's request method (I have to do a POST). Also implementing it in Azure Functions.

**Edit**
I have modified the code and it retries HTTP errors but not socket or connection errors. [Doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_aborted) says, in case of socket errors, first on('socket') and then on('error') will be called. But my app never retries when there is a ECONNRESET or ETIMEDOUT error.

```
async function fetchWithRetry(options, reqBody,context) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let attempts = 1;
        const fetch_retry = (options, n) => {
            let httpsReq = httpsClient.request(options, function (res) {
                const code = res.statusCode;
                const message = res.statusMessage;
                if (n === 0) {
                    reject({
                        'status': code,
                        'message': message
                    });
                } else if (code < 200 || code >= 300) {
                    context.log("Retry again: Got back code: " + code + " message: " + message);
                    context.log("With delay " + attempts * delay);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        attempts++;
                        fetch_retry(options, n - 1);
                    }, attempts * delay);
                } else if (code === 201) {
                    resolve({
                        'status': code,
                        'message': message
                    });
                } else {
                    var body = '';
                    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        body = body + chunk;
                    });
                    res.on('end', function () {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                    });
                }
                httpsReq.on('error', function (error) {
                    context.log("Retry again: Got back code: " + code + " message: " + message + " error: " + error);
                    context.log("With delay " + attempts * delay);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        attempts++;
                        fetch_retry(options, n - 1);
                    }, attempts * delay);
                });
            });
            httpsReq.write(reqBody);
            httpsReq.end();
        };
        return fetch_retry(options, numberOfRetries);
    });

}
```

When an error occurs, the code calls the end() and my function dies. Can I please get some help to fix it. Also trying to wrap it around a promise because that is the best practice.

Comment: Does your code get into `res.on('end',function()` code block? What's the status code being returned?

Comment: @GauravMantri The app works if there is no HTTP error, but my calling api has 5000 requests/ seconds limitation. I get ETIMEDOUT or ECONNRESET errors and in those cases, the app is not retrying. Very strange. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return resolve(json);` just `resolve(json);`, and instead of `throw reject(json);` just `reject(json);`

Comment: Thanks I have modified the code, but its not retrying on socket or connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, catch the socket errors on the request error handler rather than response

```
`Req.on('error', function (error) {
            context.log("Retry again: " + error);
            context.log("With delay " + attempts * delay);
            setTimeout(() => {
                attempts++;
                fetch_retry(options, n - 1);
            }, attempts * delay);
        });`
```